# Error Trying to install NatTable Core in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, nattable

Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2

Trying to use Download site "http://download.eclipse.org/nattable/releases/1.5.0/repository/"

to install "NatTable Core Features"

Error:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.rcp,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Problems downloading artifact:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core,1.5.0.201703192131.
>   Error reading signed
>   content:C:\Users\Glen\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1629518335572249543.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   C:\Users\Glen\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1629518335572249543.jar
>   Problems downloading artifact:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core.feature,1.5.0.201703192131.
>   Error reading signed
>   content:C:\Users\Glen\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8522004777182375322.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   C:\Users\Glen\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8522004777182375322.jar

Comment: did you uncheck "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" while installing nattable ?

Comment: Yes. That error isn't about trying to contact sites is it?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Indigo is more than 5 years old. NatTable 1.5 is quite new. I suppose the signatures doesn't match with that difference.

I suggest to update the IDE to a more current version like Oxygen and use a Target Definition if you need to stick with Indigo as the base of your application. From my point of view there is no reason to stick with such an old version of an IDE.